# Angular directive to update height of multiple elements to match the tallest

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm fairly new to Angular's directives and am trying to figure out the proper way to use them. I'm using an ng-repeat to populate a list of elements. Once the repeater is loaded I want to look at each element and find which one is the tallest (has the most text in it) and then force all of the elements to that size.

A way of accomplishing this in jQuery would be like so:

```
var tallest = 0;
// Loop through each element
$('.element-class').each(function () {
    var thisHeight = $(this).height();      
    if (thisHeight > tallest)
        tallest = thisHeight;
});
// Apply height to all elements
$('.element-class').height(tallest);
```

Would someone be able to instruct me as to how i might accomplish this with a directive (or another more fitting Angular way). The repeater looks something like this.

```
<div class="element-class" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div class="element-title" ng-bind="item.title"></div>
    <p class="element-text" ng-bind="item.description"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: not a fan of css flexbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what you can do. Using a directive you can keep track of each element and on the final element call a function that will calculate the height of each and find the tallest then set all elements to that height. You will need to use angular's `$timeout` in order to make sure that you don't check for the heights until after angular has finished manipulating the dom. Here's some code and below I've placed a [link to a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/X4jmwZ?p=preview).

**HTML**

```
<div equalize-height>
  <div class="element-class" equalize-height-add="item" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div class="element-title" ng-bind="item.title"></div>
    <p class="element-text" ng-bind="item.description"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Angular**

```
.directive('equalizeHeight', ['$timeout', function($timeout){
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  controller: function($scope){
    console.log('equalizeHeightFor - controller');
    var elements = [];
    this.addElement = function(element){
      console.log('adding element:', element);
      elements.push(element);
      console.log(elements);
    }

    // resize elements once the last element is found
    this.resize = function(){
      $timeout(function(){
        console.log('finding the tallest ...');
        // find the tallest
        var tallest = 0, height;
        angular.forEach(elements, function(el){
          height = el[0].offsetHeight;
          console.log('height:', height);
          if(height > tallest)
            tallest = height;
          // console.log(el);
        });
        console.log('tallest:', tallest);
        console.log('resizing ...');
        // resize
        angular.forEach(elements, function(el){
          el[0].style.height = tallest + 'px';
        });
        console.log('-- finished --');
      }, 0);
    };
  }
};
}])

.directive('equalizeHeightAdd', [function($timeout){
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  require: '^^equalizeHeight',
  link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl_for){
    console.log('equalizeHeightAdd - link');
    // add element to list of elements
    ctrl_for.addElement(element);
    if(scope.$last)
      ctrl_for.resize();
  }
};
}])
```

Here's a link to a plunker too see it in action:
http://plnkr.co/edit/X4jmwZ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You need run your code exact after ng-repeat last element has rendered on view.

Angular way solution would be like below.

**HTML**

```
<div class="element-class" on-finish-ng-repeat-render ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div class="element-title" ng-bind="item.title"></div>
    <p class="element-text" ng-bind="item.description"></p>
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('onFinishNgRepeatRender', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            if (scope.$last === true) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    //this coade will execute right after ng-repeat rendering has been completed
                    var tallest = 0, currentElement = angular.element(element);
                    // Loop through each element
                    angular.forEach(angular.element(element), function(value, key) {
                        var thisHeight = angular.element(value).height();
                        if (thisHeight > tallest)
                            tallest = thisHeight;
                    });
                    // Apply height to all elements
                    currentElement.height(tallest);
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Comment: @LoganGarland does it helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

I want to do same. This thread help me a lot. After some trouble here is the solution which I found.

Thing I want to do is get all element's length and set all element length as tallest of all.

So for that first I need to detect when ng-repeat finishes loading through directive, and in that directive, once I detect that the last one has finished loading, I have to find tallest length of all element and apply it to all element.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-4" ng-repeat="category in categoriesList.categories" set-max-height> 
  <div class="catagory-item">
    <h1 class="text-center">{{category}}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

1) `set-max-height` is a directive name.
2) `category-item` is class, by using this class name I want to get all elements height and set it as max height of all element.

Directive

```
app.directive('setMaxHeight', ['$timeout',function($timeout) {
return {
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        //Belove code will run afer ng-repeat finished
        if ($scope.$last){

            //Get all element by class name
            var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("catagory-item");
            var maxHeight = 0;

            $timeout(function(){
                // Get the max height from all div
                for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                   var elementHeight = elements[i].offsetHeight;
                   if (elements[i].offsetHeight > maxHeight) {
                       maxHeight = elementHeight;
                   }
                }
                // set max height to the all div
                for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                    elements[i].style.height = maxHeight + "px"; 
                }   
            });

        }
    }
}
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

[ragamufin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599626/angular-directive-to-update-height-of-multiple-elements-to-match-the-tallest/28601239#28601239) works like a charm (thank you!)

But if you plan on filtering or adding new element in the middle of the repeat, you should loose that 'if' in the end of the 'equalizeHeightAdd' directive (otherwise it won't resize itself) and implement a remove function on the controller and remove elements if they are destroyed:

```
    .directive('equalizeHeight', equalizeHeight)
    .directive('equalizeHeightAdd', equalizeHeightAdd);

    equalizeHeight.$inject = ['$timeout'];

    /* @ngInject */
    function equalizeHeight() {
        var directive = {
            bindToController: true,
            controller: ControllerName,
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            link: link,
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {}
        };
        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {

        }
    }

    ControllerName.$inject = ['$window', '$timeout'];

    /* @ngInject */
    function ControllerName($window, $timeout) {
        var elements = [];
        this.addElement = addElement;
        this.removeElement = removeElement;
        this.resize = resize;

        activate();

        function activate() {
            angular.element($window).on('resize', function () {
                angular.forEach(elements, function(el){
                    el[0].style.height = null;
                });
                resize();
            });
        }

        function addElement(element){
            elements.push(element);
            console.log(elements.length);
        }

        function removeElement(element){
            elements.splice(elements.indexOf(element),1);
        }

        // resize elements once the last element is found
        function resize(){
            $timeout(function(){
                // find the tallest
                var tallest = 0, height;
                angular.forEach(elements, function(el){
                    height = el[0].offsetHeight;
                    if(height > tallest)
                        tallest = height;
                });
                // resize
                angular.forEach(elements, function(el){
                    el[0].style.height = tallest + 'px';
                });
            }, 0);
        }
    }

    /* @ngInject */
    function equalizeHeightAdd(){
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: '^^equalizeHeight',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl_for){
                // add element to list of elements
                ctrl_for.addElement(element);
                ctrl_for.resize();
                element.on('$destroy', function () {
                    ctrl_for.removeElement(element);
                    ctrl_for.resize();
                });
            }
        };
    }
```

> Sorry, I can not add comment to his answer, because of the lack of reputations, but I think this is a pretty important addition. Also sorry for the different formating, but this is how I use it in my project, but basically it's the same.